# SQL Server Query to get latest items

Tags: sql, sql-server, rdbms

I have the following information in a table. Assume that we have various fruits where each crate of fruit can have one of the three quality level (Good, bad, and average).

I want to query the table to get the latest quality status of a fruit.

**Fruit   Quality  Timestamp**



Orange   Good       Nov 10, 11:20 AM   
Apple    Bad       Nov 10, 11:10 AM  
Banana   Good       Nov 10, 10 AM  
Apple   Average       Nov 10, 8 AM  
Grapes   Bad       Nov 10, 7 AM  
Grapes   Average       Nov 10, 6:45 AM   
Apple   Good       Nov 10, 6:20 AM  
Banana   Good       Nov 10, 5 AM  
Orange   Average       Nov 9, 11 AM  
Orange   Bad       Nov 9, 10:20 AM  
Apple   Good       Nov 9, 8:20 AM  
Grapes   Good       Nov 9, 5 AM  
Mango   Bad       Nov 9, 4 AM

Result of query should be: 
Orange Good 
Apple Bad 
Banana Good 
Grapes Bad 
Mango Bad

I am a newbie and struggling with this query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post some of the SQL you have tried?

Comment: Sure...I have looked correlated queries and some basic simple queries.. SELECT        Fruit, Quality, TimeStamp
FROM            Analytics
WHERE        (Quality= 'Bad' OR
                         Quality = 'Good' OR
                         Quality = 'Average' OR
                         AND (MerchantInfo = '334532')
ORDER BY TimeStamp DESC .. I also explored Group By but that cannot be used here as I don't have any aggregate function. Also, joins and correlated queries also seems useless here.

Comment: I am exploring the ways to group this table by Fruit, order each group by timestamp and get Top(1) item from each group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH fruitStatus
AS
(
    SELECT fruit, quality, [timestamp],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY Fruit ORDER BY [TimeStamp] DESC) rn
    FROM    tableName
)
SELECT fruit, quality
FROM fruitStatus
WHERE rn = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a window aggregate function along with the QUALIFY clause?

```
SELECT Fruit
     , Grade
  FROM MyTable
 QUALIFY MAX(Timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY Fruit) = Timestamp
```

You should also be able to accomplish it this way:

```
SELECT Fruit
     , Grade
  FROM MyTable T1
 INNER JOIN
      (SELECT Fruit
            , MAX(Timestamp) AS MaxTimeStamp
         FROM MyTable
        GROUP BY 1) DT1
    ON T1.Fruit = DT1.Fruit
   AND T1.TimeStamp = DT1.MaxTimeStamp;
```

Comment: I also upvoted your answer :D I'm also a big fan on subquery (*which is on your second example*) because it works on almost all rdbms, and especially with the question is tag only by `sql`.

Comment: @Rob Paller, has Qualify clause been included in Sql Server?

Comment: I'm afraid it may not support it yet. John Woo's solution shows a possible workaround with the window aggregate of Row_Number and it is also why I included a second alternative using a standard aggregate.